# How to run Kafka Streams with Ktor

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, ktor

I'm deploying a Kafka Streams application to OpenShift, and I'm using Ktor + Netty as the server framework. I'm facing a problem where it seems like the Netty server (or Ktor application) blocks the Kafka Streams instance. My code is as follows:

```kotlin
object AppLogger : ILogging by Logging<AppLogger>()

private val log = AppLogger.log

fun main() {
    val appConfig = ConfigVariables(HoconApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.load()))
    val promRegistry = PrometheusObject.prometheusRegistry

    val topicSerdeConfig =
        TopicSerdeConfig(
            appConfig.streamKtableTopic,
            appConfig.streamInputTopic,
            appConfig.streamOutputTopic,
            appConfig.schemaRegistry,
        )
    val stream = setupStream(appConfig, topicSerdeConfig, promRegistry)
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {}
    setupServerEndpoints(server, stream)

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
        Thread {
            try {
                log.atInfo().setMessage("Running shutdown hook").log()

                log.atInfo().setMessage("Pausing Kafka Streams").log()
                stream.pause()

                log.atInfo().setMessage("Closing Kafka Streams").log()
                stream.close(Duration.ofSeconds(12))

                log.atInfo().setMessage("Closing Prometheus registry").log()
                promRegistry.close()

                log.atInfo().setMessage("Stopping Netty server").log()
                server.stop(15000, 25000)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                log.atError().setMessage("Error during shutdown").log()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        },
    )

    stream.start()
    log.atInfo().setMessage("Stream is running").log()
    server.start(wait = true)
}

fun setupServerEndpoints(server: NettyApplicationEngine, stream: KafkaStreams) {
    val application = server.application

    application.install(Routing) {
        prometheusController()
        healthController(stream)
        configController()
    }
```

When running the application the message "Stream is running" is never logged - why is that? Further, when the application is deployed and running in OpenShift, it seems like the server blocks all streams processing and utlimately none of my Kafka events are processsed.

What is best practice when running Kafka Streams with Ktor and deplying it to OpenShift?

Comment: Can you determine what exact line of the code causes the blocking?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it seems like `server.start(wait = true)` takes up the whole thread. The Stream is not processing any data, even though it logs that it has started.

Comment: If the `wait` is `true` then the call blocks the current thread. You can pass the `false` to the `wait` parameter to avoid the blocking.